# view.parentView is null in Component template after upgrade to Ember 1.7.0 (or 1.8.1)

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to upgrade my app from Ember 1.6.0 to 1.7.0 (and eventually 1.8.1) and I'm running into some issues. In the template of a component I'm using:

```
{{action 'someMethodOnParentView' target=view.parentView}}
```

The template looks something like:

```
{{#parent-component}}
  {{#child-component}}
    <a href='#'>{{action "actionOnParentComponent" target=view.parentView}}>Click me</a>
  {{/child-component}}
{{/parent-component}}
```

And ParentComponent has:

```
ParentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    actionOnParentComponent: function(){ console.log('do stuff');}
  }
});
```

This was working correctly in 1.6.0, but since the update, whenever I click the element, I get:

```
Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
```

It seems like `view` and therefore `view.parentView` are null, or at least that's what I'm guessing from trying to output `{{view}}` and `{{view.parentView}}`.

Here's a JSBin of my situation [working in 1.6.0](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vuwikubahe/3/edit) and [not working in 1.7.0](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vuwikubahe/4/edit).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Block components keep the context of their parent, in other words, the entire context here is the application view.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rixiliniji/1/edit?html,js,output

You'll need to rethink your structure (or hack it ;)  http://emberjs.com/guides/components/wrapping-content-in-a-component/

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be the case precisely. Apparently that [was a bug](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4985#issuecomment-52993030) that got fixed, but caused issues on everyone depending on that behaviour. Seems like I'll have to [switch my components into views](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24434153/302246)

Comment: Oddly, according to [this post](http://ember.zone/the-confusion-around-ember-views-and-components/), Yehuda Katz and Tom Dale have advised _against_ using Views...

Comment: Here's the [updated JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wegawopeni/2/edit?html,js,console,output) using views with Ember 1.7.0.